# Google Script: Can not sort a range with getRangeByName

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need order by alphabet a list in a range by name, but for some reason fail in some point and give me a "The cell reference is out of range." in line `var tmp_range = raw_range.sort( 1 );`

The weird think is in the first call seems to work but with the sencond call (with other range name) fail.

```
function getValuesOfRange( range_name ){
  var raw_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName( range_name );
  Logger.log( raw_range );
  if ( raw_range != null ){
    Logger.log( range_name );
    var tmp_range = raw_range.sort( 1 );
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause is you are providing wrong index inside the parameter. The sort function takes different types of argument. Check here

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj

```
// Sorts by the values in the first column (A)
 range.sort(1);
```

So for example if your named range is from `'Sheet1'!D1:D9`
The sorting should be like `range.sort(4);`

So in your case change `raw_range.sort( 1 )` to `raw_range.sort( raw_range.getColumn())`

Comment: Thx. I change `raw_range.sort( 1 )` by `raw_range.sort( raw_range.getColumn() )` and work perfect. Can you edit your answer with this code to mark as correct answer?

Comment: Updated the anwser